# How to superimpose one image on another that has a different perspective?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

I would like to take the menu image, below, and superimpose it on top of the screen in the image below it, so it looks like the person is looking at that on their screen.

Is this easily done in Photoshop, or is it a bad idea for a beginner-intermediate to try?? I would assume it requires some kind of mesh that can change the perspective of the menu. I'm using PS CS6.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's pretty easy in any graphics tool that offers a 'distort' tool--which I think Photoshop does. You essentially drag each of the 4 corners of the image you have onto the 4 corners of the image in perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this and the conclusion is that you don't need perspective transformation. Just rotate the image. If you want to apply perspective, try the following. Select the layer with your new screen picture. Press Ctrl+T. Then hold Ctrl and drag the corners until you achieve the desired perspective. Ideally you want to drag the corners to the corners of the phone display. In this case you don't see them, so you have to guess.

This is how it looks with rotation:

[image]

I also applied a little bit of black Inner Glow, to make it look a little bit more natural.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for testing that for me. If I may ask, how did you get the image to appear "behind" his thumb? Was that just by erasing that part of the layer?

Comment: @zakgottlieb I masked the screenshot layer where the thumb is. You can delete that part but it's much better to mask.